# How to generate a dropdown list from another?

Tags: asp.net

I want to generate a drop down list from another drop down list. That is I have a dropdown of countries. When selecting a country,another dropdown must come with values as states of that specific country. How to do that in asp.net using c#?

Comment: Can you tell us what have you tried till now?

Comment: A little confuse ! `must come with values as states of that specific country`  ? Can you explain this to me more detail ?

Comment: In aspx page               <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLCountry" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectCountry">
        <asp:ListItem>--Select-- </asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>India</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>England</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Australia</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Pakistan</asp:ListItem>
        
    </asp:DropDownList>               In aspx.cs page   protected void SelectCountry(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DDLCountry.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                //I dont know what to write here
            }
    }

Answer (score 0):

for each country you have, add a new list item to the drop down list, with text the country and the value some id of the country. On the second drop down list, set the auto post back property to true and add an event to the on selected item change. In the event code, get the selected item and by the second ddl.
Try it!

Tip: add a hidden field on the page, and on the selected item changed event from the first ddl, set the value of the hidden field, the selected value. On the page_load event, verify if the value is string.empty and if is an id in the value. If it is, bind the second ddl.

Answer (score 0):

The technology you're looking for is called a Cascading Dropdown.

If you are using WebForms then Ajax Control Toolkit then this has one built in:

- http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

Otherwise you might need to do a further search if you are using MVC.

PS I'm not particularly proud of posting a link to the Ajax Control Toolkit as its not the best library out there but it is an easy drop in for what you want. If you're serious about doing a good job then I'd search for better options for cascading dropdowns.